# No assets in CryEngine V?

Tags: cryengine

I just downloaded and installed CryEngine 5.0.1. I am trying to follow the Island tutorial but I don't have the assets the tutor has. I have installing CryEngine Game SDK but I still don't see any assets or materials except the default ones. So my question is how do I install the assets I need to follow the tutorials?

Comment: yeah those free assets can be downloaded here:
[CRYENGINE GameSDK Sample Project](https://www.cryengine.com/marketplace/product/cryengine-gamesdk-sample-project)

Comment: There really isn't any clear answer on where you are supposed to place the downloaded files. Nor does anything specify WHAT files you are supposed to copy. I'm confused. I want to add all downloaded assets to my project but I don't know which folders/files to copy where.

Answer (score 4):

CryEngine V does not actually come with the default project and assets that came with its predecessors. As a result, you will need to download, and then import the assets into your current project. The SDK, itself, can also be run as its own project.

#### Downloading the SDK and other assets

Before you download the SDK, you first need to register them to your account. You can do this for free, once you have logged in to the marketplace. You will find the SDK listed under [CRYENGINE GameSDK Sample Project](https://www.cryengine.com/marketplace/product/cryengine-gamesdk-sample-project).

While you are there, it might be worth having a look at registering [the other assets provided by Crytek](https://www.cryengine.com/marketplace/publisher/694795776?p=1), as this makes it easier to acquire them from you launcher, later. Included in the list is a [CryEngine V Beginner's Pack](https://www.cryengine.com/marketplace/product/cryengine-v-beginners-pack) and [an elephant](https://www.cryengine.com/marketplace/product/ryse-elephant).

Once you have gone through the process of registering the assets, you can download them from the CryEngine Launcher. Once open, go to *Library > My Assets* to view all the assets registered to your account. You can download or update your assets from in here.

[image: The assets page of the CryEngine Launcher]

#### Importing assets into your project

Unfortunately, CryEngine V does not provide automated functionality to import assets into your project. Fortunately, assets can still be moved between projects fairly easily. All you need to do is find the assets *.pak* files, and drop them into the assets folder for your project.

Downloaded asset folders should be placed in the same "Crytek" directory as the base CryEngine editor. That said, you can find them easily from the launcher. Go to *Library > My Assets*, and ensure that the assets are downloaded. Once the status is *Installed*, you should have an arrow you can click on for a drop down menu. From this menu, select *Reveal in Explorer*.

Your own projects should be placed in *Documents > CRYENGINE Projects*, but you can locate the directories directly from the launcher, by clicking on the cog button next to your project name and selecting *Reveal in Explorer*. You want to be copying your new assets to the internal *Assets* folder.

#### Loading the SDK as its own project

It might be easier or more manageable to simply open the SDK, itself. Once located, you can open  *GameSDK.cryproject* in its root directory to open the scene into CryEngine.

You may also want to save this reference to your CryEngine Launcher, so the SDK project comes up in your list of available projects. From the CryEngine Launcher, select *Import*, and locate the root directory of the SDK. This will be the same folder where its *.cryproject* can be found. Once selected and confirmed, *CRYENGINE SDK* should appear as an option in your projects view.

[image: Adding the CRYENGINE SDK to the project view]

Comment: I've done this, but the one thing that doesn't seem to want to be imported is the Human AI entity. I've literally copied over the full Assets folder from the GameSDK project into my own custom project and I get a large number of assets and entities brought across but, for the life of me, I cannot fathom how to get the Human AI.

Answer (score 1):

Cryengine V starts as a blank slate unlike Cryengine 3.  If you've downloaded the GameSDK from the marketplace you still have to create a project that include assets.  I would "Add Existing" project and navigate to and select the GameSDK folder.